# Why won't Meteor autoForm afQuickField Errors display on error?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

In our Meteor `v1.11.1` application, we are using Bootstrap 3, `aldeed:autoform@6.3.0`, and `aldeed:collection2@3.2.1` in blaze to validate forms. We really want to implement the "least-custom" solution to display and validate our form inputs.

**We can't wrap our heads around why even the most basic error message doesn't appear in the form when we submit?** We narrowed the form down to one field and a submit. The HTML elements are in the DOM, but no hint of messaging appears upon validation.

The schema for the form is:

```
Folios = new Mongo.Collection('Folios')
FolioSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  "name": {
    "type": String,
    "min": 2,
    "required": true
  }
},
{
  "requiredByDefault": false,
  "clean": {
    "filter": true,
    "autoconvert": true,
    "removeEmptyStrings": true,
    "trimStrings": true,
    "getAutoValues": true,
    "removeNullsFromArrays": true
  }
}
Folios.attachSchema(FolioSchema)
```

The form is:

```
{{# autoForm id="newFolio"
  class="newFolioForm"
  collection=getFormCollection
  schema=getFormSchema
  type=getFormType
  validation="submitThenBlur"
  resetOnSuccess=true
  }}
  {{> afQuickField name='name' type='text' }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{{/ autoForm }}
```

And the helpers for `collection`, `schema`, and `type` are:

```
Template.newFolioForm.helpers({
  getFormCollection()
  {
    return Folios
  },
  getFormSchema()
  {
    return FolioSchema
  },
  getFormType()
  {
    return "insert"
  }
})
```

When I click submit, no error message, no error class, nothin'.  We've consulted [simpl-schema docs](https://github.com/aldeed/simpl-schema#customizing-validation-messages). We want to avoid the need to implement [afMessage](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform#affieldmessage) as a part of a fully custom form just to get a message and validation error to display properly.

I thought to check here first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the missing `Tracker` that is required in order to generate reactive validation messages:

```js
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'

FolioSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    'name': {
      'type': String,
      'min': 2,
      'required': true
    }
  },
  {
    'requiredByDefault': false,
    'clean': {
      'filter': true,
      'autoconvert': true,
      'removeEmptyStrings': true,
      'trimStrings': true,
      'getAutoValues': true,
      'removeNullsFromArrays': true
    },
    tracker: Tracker // this line is important
  })
```

Without passing the Tracker, there is no cause for the template to redraw, since there is no dependency resolved.

Readings: https://github.com/aldeed/simpl-schema#enable-meteor-tracker-reactivity

Comment: I passed over this detail! Are you available for challenging Meteor work?

Comment: You're welcome. Let's discuss further things in the Meteor chatroom here on StackOverflow: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225553/meteor-talk

Comment: Just did. Reach me and we'll get going if everything aligns.